# Cómo mostrar mensajes en el panel de administracióin de wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

Estoy creando un plugin para wordpress que me conecta el plugin de gestión de tiendas que estoy usando con los usuarios de mi página web de manera que al insertar una tienda me crea un usuario con los datos de la tienda y con un rol específico, el objetivo es tener una especie de b2b.

Hasta aquí funciona todo correctamente, el problema es que una vez terminada la acción de convertir tienda en usuario e insertar todos los datos en la bd, necesito mostrar un mensaje al administrador y no consigo que se muestre.

Ésta es la función que transforma la tienda en usuario y lo añade a la bd, básicamente una vez insertado el usuario crea un mensaje informando al administrador de qué es lo que ha ocurrido y si ha creado un usuario nuevo o si ha modificado uno existente. Luego lo almacena usando `update_option()`.

```
function add_customer($post_id){
global $wpsl_admin;

if ( empty( $_POST['wpsl_meta_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wpsl_meta_nonce'], 'save_store_meta' ) )
    return;
if ( !isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) || 'wpsl_stores' !== $_POST['post_type'] )
    return;
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;
if ( is_int( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) )
    return;
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return;
$store_data = $_POST['wpsl'];
$store_title= get_the_title($post_id);
$email=$store_data['email'];
if(!username_exists($email) and !email_exists($email) ){
    $pass = create_password($store_data['CIF'],$store_title);
    $contact=explode(" ",$store_data['Contacto']);
    $first_name=$contact[0];
    count($contact)>1?$last_name=$contact[1]:$last_name=" ";
    $user_data=array(
        'user_login'=>$email,
        'user_pass'=>$pass,
        'first_name'=>$first_name,
        'last_name'=>$last_name,
        'user_url'=>$store_data['url'],
        'role'=>'tienda',
        'display_name'=>$store_title,
        'user_nicename'=> str_replace(" ","-",$store_title),
        'user_email'=>$email,
    );
     wp_insert_user( $user_data );

    $notice= "Se ha añadido el usuario para la tienda, los datos de acceso son: <br>
                Usuario: $email<br>
                Contraseña: $pass";

    update_option('store2customer_notice', $notice);
    add_action( 'admin_notices','store2customer_notices' );
}else{

    $id=username_exists($store_data['email']);
    if(empty($id)){
        $id=email_exists($store_data['email']);
    }
    wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $id, 'role' =>'tienda' ) );
    $usuario= get_user_by('id',$id);
    $notice= "Se le ha asignado el perfil tienda al usuario $usuario->user_nicename<br>";
    update_option('store2customer_notice', $notice);

    add_action( 'post_updated_messages','store2customer_notices' );
 }
}
 add_filter('save_post','add_customer',10,1);
```

Luego utiliza `add_action( 'admin_notices','store2customer_notices' );` para, mediante el hook 'admin_notices' ejecutar la función
    'store2customer_notices' cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
function store2customer_notices(){
$class = 'notice notice-success is-dismissible';
$notice= get_option('store2customer_notice');
printf( '<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', $class, $notice );
delete_option('store2customer_notice');
}
```

Esta función rescata el valor almacenado en 'store2customer_notice' que se corresponde con el mensaje a mostrar al administrador.

Lo que obtengo es la nada más absoluta, tengo el `WP_DEBUG` en `true` y la acción de guardar el mensaje específico funciona porque si añado estas líneas:

```
    $noticia= get_option('store2customer_notice');
    echo $noticia;exit;
```

Justo después de esta:

```
 update_option('store2customer_notice', $notice);
```

Me muestra el mensaje correcto, el fallo debe estar en:

`add_action( 'admin_notices','store2customer_notices' );` o bien en la función `store2customer_notices()` pero no consigo saber cuál es.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, ya he encontrado la solución, lo único que fallaba era la ubicación de la sentencia `add_action( 'admin_notices','store2customer_notices' );` Yo creía que había que ubicarla justo cuando quieres que se muestre el mensaje, en mi caso una vez hecha la inserción en la bd para mostrar el resultado al administrador, pero la ubicación correcta era fuera de la función. pongo el código corregido:

```
function store2customer_notices(){
$class = 'updated notice-success is-dismissible';
if ($notices= get_option('store2customer_notice')){
printf( '<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', $class, $notice );
delete_option('store2customer_notice');
 }
}

add_action( 'admin_notices','store2customer_notices' );

function add_customer($post_id){

global $wpsl_admin;

if ( empty( $_POST['wpsl_meta_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wpsl_meta_nonce'], 'save_store_meta' ) )
    return;
if ( !isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) || 'wpsl_stores' !== $_POST['post_type'] )
    return;
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;
if ( is_int( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) )
    return;
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return;

$store_data = $_POST['wpsl'];
$store_title= get_the_title($post_id);
$email=$store_data['email'];
if(!username_exists($email) and !email_exists($email) ){
    $pass = create_password($store_data['CIF'],$store_title);
    $contact=explode(" ",$store_data['Contacto']);
    $first_name=$contact[0];
    count($contact)>1?$last_name=$contact[1]:$last_name=" ";
    $user_data=array(
        'user_login'=>$email,
        'user_pass'=>$pass,
        'first_name'=>$first_name,
        'last_name'=>$last_name,
        'user_url'=>$store_data['url'],
        'role'=>'tienda',
        'display_name'=>$store_title,
        'user_nicename'=> str_replace(" ","-",$store_title),
        'user_email'=>$email,
    );
     wp_insert_user( $user_data );

    $notice= "Se ha añadido el usuario para la tienda, los datos de acceso son: <br>
                Usuario: $email<br>
                Contraseña: $pass";
    update_option('store2customer_notice', $notice);

}else{
    $id=username_exists($store_data['email']);
    if(empty($id)){
        $id=email_exists($store_data['email']);
    }

    $usuario= get_user_by('id',$id);

    if(in_array("administrator",$usuario->roles)){
        $notice= "No se ha modificado el perfil del usuario ".$usuario->data->user_nicename.", por ser administrador <br>";

    }else{
        wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $id, 'role' =>'tienda' ) );
        $notice= "Se le ha asignado el perfil tienda al usuario ".$usuario->data->user_nicename."<br>";

    }
    update_option('store2customer_notice', $notice);
}

}
add_filter('save_post','add_customer',10,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está en la función `store2customer_notices`, intenta hacer un loop de las noticias pendientes y utilizar `echo` en lugar de `printf`:

```
function store2customer_notices() {
  if ($notices= get_option('store2customer_notice')) {
    foreach ($notices as $notice) {
      echo "<div class='notice notice-success is-dismissible'><p>$notice</p></div>";
    }
    delete_option('store2customer_notice');
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, he probado tu solución y tampoco funcionaba, la solución la escribo abajo.